# get mp3 play time using eye3d with python

Tags: python, time, mp3, playback, eyed3

I'm having a hard time returning the play time of an mp3 using the eye3d python module...I can retrieve tag information, etc, with the following:

```
import eyed3

def getInfo():
    srcPath = r'C:\aaa'
    os.chdir(srcPath) #change working directory

    inf = eyed3.core.load('test.mp3')

    print inf.tag.album
```

but can't grasp how to use "class eyed3.core.AudioInfo[source]" seen here (http://eyed3.nicfit.net/api/eyed3.html) to get play time.  I simply want to return how long the song is (then eventually iterate over a playlist to find the playlist play time).

thanks

Comment: class eyed3.core.AudioInfo.time_secs it is clearly there.returns playtime http://eyed3.nicfit.net/api/eyed3.html#eyed3.core.AudioInfo see that

Comment: Yes, but what is the syntax?  inf.AudioInfo.time_sec gives an error.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple:

```
af = eyed3.load('my_mp3_file.mp3')
duration = af.info.time_secs
```

Not sure this is documented anywhere, but I was able to figure this out by poking at things in iPython.

If you prefer a one-liner you could also do:

```
duration = eyed3.load('my_mp3_file.mp3').info.time_secs
```

I should note that this value can be pretty far off for variable bit rate mp3s. This is because it determines the length by sampling mp3 frames, and making a guess about the overall track. With variable bit rates, this means that if the audio at the beginning of the track isn't representative, the guess will be poor.

Comment: old question I know, is it possible to get the bitrate?

Answer (score 3):

@user1526973 @mlissner s answer was correct and I was inspired to create this, here is my version of a working product.

@twigg Yes you can get the bitrate.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# =============================================================================
"""Module Built to To Read ID3 Track Data."""
# File Name: track_meta_id3.py
# =============================================================================
import time
from os import path

from eyed3 import id3
from eyed3 import load


current_home = path.expanduser('~')
search_dir = path.join(current_home + "/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Rush/Chronicles (Disc 2)/2-03 Limelight.mp3")  # noqa


def track_info(filename):
    """Module Built To Read ID3 Track Data."""
    tag = id3.Tag()
    tag.parse(filename)
    a = load(filename)
    print("# {}".format('=' * 78))
    print("Track Name:     {}".format(tag.title))
    print("Track Artist:   {}".format(tag.artist))
    print("Track Album:    {}".format(tag.album))
    print("Track Duration: {}".format(duration_from_seconds(a.info.time_secs)))
    print("Track Number:   {}".format(tag.track_num))
    print("Track BitRate:  {}".format(a.info.bit_rate))
    print("Track BitRate:  {}".format(a.info.bit_rate_str))
    print("Sample Rate:    {}".format(a.info.sample_freq))
    print("Mode:           {}".format(a.info.mode))
    print("# {}".format('=' * 78))
    print("Album Artist:         {}".format(tag.album_artist))
    print("Album Year:           {}".format(tag.getBestDate()))
    print("Album Recording Date: {}".format(tag.recording_date))
    print("Album Type:           {}".format(tag.album_type))
    print("Disc Num:             {}".format(tag.disc_num))
    print("Artist Origin:        {}".format(tag.artist_origin))
    print("# {}".format('=' * 78))
    print("Artist URL:         {}".format(tag.artist_url))
    print("Audio File URL:     {}".format(tag.audio_file_url))
    print("Audio Source URL:   {}".format(tag.audio_source_url))
    print("Commercial URL:     {}".format(tag.commercial_url))
    print("Copyright URL:      {}".format(tag.copyright_url))
    print("Internet Radio URL: {}".format(tag.internet_radio_url))
    print("Publisher URL:      {}".format(tag.publisher_url))
    print("Payment URL:        {}".format(tag.payment_url))
    print("# {}".format('=' * 78))
    print("Publisher: {}".format(tag.publisher))
    print("Original Release Date: {}".format(tag.original_release_date))
    print("Play Count: {}".format(tag.play_count))
    print("Tagging Date: {}".format(tag.tagging_date))
    print("Release Date: {}".format(tag.release_date))
    print("Terms Of Use: {}".format(tag.terms_of_use))
    print("isV1: {}".format(tag.isV1()))
    print("isV2: {}".format(tag.isV2()))
    print("BPM: {}".format(tag.bpm))
    print("Cd Id: {}".format(tag.cd_id))
    print("Composer: {}".format(tag.composer))
    print("Encoding date: {}".format(tag.encoding_date))
    print("# {}".format('=' * 78))
    print("Genre: {}".format(tag.genre.name))
    print("Non Std Genre Name: {}".format(tag.non_std_genre.name))
    print("Genre ID: {}".format(tag.genre.id))
    print("Non Std Genre ID: {}".format(tag.non_std_genre.id))
    print("LAME Tag:       {}".format(a.info.lame_tag))
    print("# {}".format('=' * 78))
    print("Header Version: {}".format(tag.header.version))
    print("Header Major Version: {}".format(tag.header.major_version))
    print("Header Minor Version: {}".format(tag.header.minor_version))
    print("Header Rev Version: {}".format(tag.header.rev_version))
    print("Header Extended: {}".format(tag.header.extended))
    print("Header Footer: {}".format(tag.header.footer))
    print("Header Experimental: {}".format(tag.header.experimental))
    print("Header SIZE: {}".format(tag.header.SIZE))
    print("Header Tag Size: {}".format(tag.header.tag_size))
    print("Extended Header Size: {}".format(tag.extended_header.size))
    print("# {}".format('=' * 78))
    print("File Name: {}".format(tag.file_info.name))
    print("File Tag Size: {}".format(tag.file_info.tag_size))
    print("File Tag Padding Size: {}".format(tag.file_info.tag_padding_size))
    print("File Read Only: {}".format(tag.read_only))
    print("File Size: {}".format(a.info.size_bytes))
    print("Last Modified: {}".format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                                     time.localtime(tag.file_info.mtime))))
    print("Last Accessed: {}".format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                                     time.localtime(tag.file_info.atime))))
    print("# {}".format('=' * 78))


def duration_from_seconds(s):
    """Module to get the convert Seconds to a time like format."""
    s = s
    m, s = divmod(s, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    d, h = divmod(h, 24)
    timelapsed = "{:01d}:{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(int(d),
                                                      int(h),
                                                      int(m),
                                                      int(s))
    return timelapsed


track_info(search_dir)
```

#### Result looks like this:

$ python3 ~/Desktop/track_meta_id3.py

```
# ==============================================================================
Track Name:     Limelight
Track Artist:   Rush
Track Album:    Chronicles (Disc 2)
Track Duration: 0:00:04:22
Track Number:   (3, 14)
Track BitRate:  (False, 320)
Track BitRate:  320 kb/s
Sample Rate:    44100
Mode:           Stereo
# ==============================================================================
Album Artist:         None
Album Year:           1990
Album Recording Date: 1990
Album Type:           None
Disc Num:             (2, 2)
Artist Origin:        [None, None, None]
# ==============================================================================
Artist URL:         None
Audio File URL:     None
Audio Source URL:   None
Commercial URL:     None
Copyright URL:      None
Internet Radio URL: None
Publisher URL:      None
Payment URL:        None
# ==============================================================================
Publisher: None
Original Release Date: None
Play Count: None
Tagging Date: None
Release Date: None
Terms Of Use: None
isV1: False
isV2: True
BPM: 0
Cd Id: None
Composer: Lee/Lifeson/Peart
Encoding date: None
# ==============================================================================
Genre: Rock
Non Std Genre Name: Rock
Genre ID: 17
Non Std Genre ID: 17
LAME Tag:       {}
# ==============================================================================
Header Version: (2, 3, 0)
Header Major Version: 2
Header Minor Version: 3
Header Rev Version: 0
Header Extended: False
Header Footer: False
Header Experimental: False
Header SIZE: 10
Header Tag Size: 56574
Extended Header Size: 0
# ==============================================================================
File Name: /Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Rush/Chronicles (Disc 2)/2-03 Limelight.mp3
File Tag Size: 56584
File Tag Padding Size: 1024
File Read Only: False
File Size: 10545396
Last Modified: 2019-08-29 14:33:51
Last Accessed: 2019-09-05 15:44:19
# ==============================================================================
```

[I also added this to my repo.](https://github.com/JayRizzo/Random_Scripts/blob/master/track_meta_id3.py)